# Delete a record in indexdb from a button in a dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with rows which gets added dynamically to the DOM from a row inside template tags. In the row I have a delete button which deletes the row from the table and should also delete the entry from the IndexDB. The method to delete the entry gets called from the onclick event listener of the delete button. The request.onsuccess from the IndexDB triggers but the database entry is not disappearing.

The same method called from the console to delete the entry with the same key is successful. Same if I call the method from a button which is not added to the DOM afterwards. So I assume the problem lays in this method which creates the table rows from a template.

UPDATED: Changed the method to not work on the document fragment table data cells from the template but on a clone (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#Avoiding_DocumentFragment_pitfall). Attaching now the event handler after appending to the table doesn't change anythinh. The handler gets attached and by click on the button the code inside gets called but still the entry is not deleted from the IndexDB.

```
/**
 * Create the visual element of the task object and its properties and append it to the
 * task table
 * 
 * @param {*} task the task data object
 */
function addTaskToTaskList(task) {

    let taskTableBody = document.querySelector('#task-table tbody');
    // get the task template
    let template = document.querySelector("#task-item-template");

    // clone the new row and insert it into the table
    let clone = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

    let tableCells = clone.querySelectorAll('td');
    // fill the cells with the data from the task object
    tableCells[0].innerHTML = task.tID;
    tableCells[1].innerHTML = task.title;
    tableCells[2].innerHTML = task.startDate;
    tableCells[3].innerHTML = task.endDate;
    tableCells[4].innerHTML = task.priority;

    // add the task node to the table
    let appendedNode = taskTableBody.appendChild(clone);

    // add eventlisteners for action buttons
    let actionBtns = appendedNode.querySelectorAll('button');
    actionBtns[1].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        let rowClicked = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        let taskID = rowClicked.querySelector('#task-id').innerHTML;
        console.log("TaskID extracted from row: " + taskID);
        Database.deleteItemInObjectStore("Tasks", taskID);
        removeTaskFromTable(rowClicked.rowIndex);
    });
}
```

The method call Database.deleteItemInObjectStore("Tasks", taskID); is correct and triggers the request.onsucces from the IndexDB objectstore, also from the button in the row I created. But the entry is not deleted from the IndexDB.

Sample rendered table:

[image: rendered table]

```
function deleteItemInObjectStore(objectStoreName, itemKey) {
        let request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion)
        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            let db = e.target.result;
            let tx = db.transaction(objectStoreName, "readwrite");
            let store = tx.objectStore(objectStoreName);

            let req = store.delete(itemKey);
            
            req.onsuccess = function () {
                console.log("DATABASE | Successful deleted from Objectstore: "+ 
                objectStoreName + " | The item with key: " + itemKey);
            }
        
            tx.oncomplete = function () {
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample console output. For example I click in the first row on delete:

```
TaskID extracted from row: 1
DATABASE | Successful deleted from Objectstore: Tasks | The item with key: 1
```

Same method called from the console with the same arguments with exactly the same output works without problems:

```
Database.deleteItemInObjectStore("Tasks", 1);
DATABASE | Successful deleted from Objectstore: Tasks | The item with key: 1
```

Comment: Since this is a HTML to JS thing via those dynamic rows, you might show the code that adds the rows (some sample data) and/or at least a rendered HTML sample  here IN the question

Comment: Note you attach an event handler before you append to the table - seems a bit backwards there.  Maybe append to the table then get a reference to that new element and attach at that point.

Comment: I added a picture of the rendered table. I will try attaching the event handler after adding the element to the table and report back. Thanks for help!

Comment: Unfortunatly no luck yet. Still same behaviour. The code inside the event handler gets called and the correct taskID gets picked from the row. I get as well the console.log from inside the request.onsuccess from the store.delete

Answer (score 0):

The solution: I get task id from the row as string but to delete the indexDB entry with the key i need to parse it as a number.

```
function deleteItemInObjectStore(objectStoreName, itemKey) {
        let request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion)
        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            let db = e.target.result;
            let tx = db.transaction(objectStoreName, "readwrite");
            let store = tx.objectStore(objectStoreName);

            let req = store.delete(Number(itemKey));
            
            req.onsuccess = function () {
                console.log("DATABASE | Successful deleted from Objectstore: "+ 
                objectStoreName + " | The item with key: " + itemKey);
            }
        
            tx.oncomplete = function () {
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }
```